# Remove editable address bar in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus

Ubuntu 11.10, Classic Gnome shell. Some time ago I set editable address in Nautilus using this way which was described at this question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/281131/re-enable-editable-file-path-in-nautilus) :

```
gconftool-2 --type=Boolean --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/always_use_location_entry true
```

Now I want to get default behavior back. I tried this:

```
gconftool-2 --type=Boolean --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/always_use_location_entry false
```

But it doesn't help. How do I get back to the default behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Command line**

Just type the following in a terminal:

`gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry false`

**Graphical**

To switch from the location bar to the path bar, you can use [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools].

To install dconf-tools, run the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

After installing it, search for dconf-tools in the dash and open it.

From there, the setting is located at *org* -> *gnome* -> *nautilus* -> *preferences*.
You need to disable `always-use-location-entry` to always use the path bar instead of the location bar.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I used: gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry false